# Conditional Component render with predetermine props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If there are codes like this:

```
const UseComponent = useXComponent ? XComponent : Fragment;
...
<UseComponent cid={cid}>
  {children}
</UseComponent>
```

Any ways to set `cid` in during `XComponent` reference? because I do not need to set the props for `Fragment`.

Thanks for the helps.

Comment: "During reference" you mean in the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html to be installed for the below to work-

```
const UseComponent = useXComponent ? XComponent : Fragment;
let props = {};
if(useXComponent) {
 props = {
  cid: cid
 }
}

<UseComponent {...props}>
  {children}
</UseComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above answer, this is the shorthand.

```
const UseComponent = useXComponent ? XComponent : Fragment;
...
<UseComponent {...(useXComponent ? {cid} : {}))>
  {children}
</UseComponent>
```